# Does PHP OOP have an equivalent to main() in Java?

Tags: php, object, coding-style

In the interest of code clarity, I'm wondering if it's possible to have an object in PHP execute a function or block as it's being defined, to keep things more Java-like.

Not as it's being instantiated via `__construct()`, but as it's being defined like `main()` in Java. Does PHP have an equivalent to `main()` in Java?

And for people with experience coding entire projects in OO PHP: How do you decide what code should and shouldn't be contained inside objects?

Comment: What? Can you elaborate better onto what you are saying?

Comment: No, it doesn't. PHP executes statements as it finds them, from the start of the file through to the end. An equivalent would be to define a class, put the `main()` code in the constructor, and then have `new MyClass()` at the end.

Comment: What is it that main and __construct have in common? Yes absolutely nothing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What code should be in objects? Well, that's quite an open-ended question: it depends.

For small projects, you could do everything procedurally. But OO does give you some benefits for larger projects, such as *encapsulation* (only granting external method/attribute access as required, and hiding mechanics of one section from other unrelated sections) and *inheritance* (great for helping solve a general case and then narrowing it down to your requirements, whilst keeping code well-organised).

For large web projects, especially those using a modern PHP framework, I'd say 80% of your code can be OO - with the exception of controllers and snippets of code in the view layers. But some systems (such as Wordpress) force a more procedural style, so your OO may only be 30% of your code (I do WP plugin development in OO, but from what I can tell that approach is unusual).

To learn more about this, you may find it helpful to choose a PHP framework (Symfony, Zend, Cake et al) and run through their tutorial. You'll learn a great deal more by *doing* than by learning in the abstract, imo.

Comment: The checkmark is also for halfer's answer in a comment on my original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to you can make a "main" function and then just call it:

```
function main(){

     $obj1 = new Obj1();
     doSomething();
     //etc...

}

main();
```

That if I understood your question correctly...

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not an OO question.  main() in Java and similar languages is a framework feature, not an OO one.  All main() defines is the entry point of the application, which is something you are doing anyway.

So the short answer is that this is irrelevant.  The longer answer is that you could look for a particular framework in PHP if you want that kind of execution order.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see main in stack-traces. It's simply the entry-point to your application. Usually the first line (or line zero) of the first file to invoke the parser.

[image]